# Asp.net Mvc2 LabelFor and DisplayName from prop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Context =>

```
${Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Foos[i].Checked)}
${Html.LabelFor(x => x.Foos[i].Checked)}
```

Problem is - i can't provide label text based on Foo.Name.

Is there out of the box method of how to modify metadata, passing in lambda x=>x.Name to change it?

Is creating another HmtlHelper extension method

```
LabelFor(this htmlhelper, [lambda], value, htmlattribs)
```

the only way?

---

[Related issue](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=4517)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eh, whatever. Workaround is acceptable. This issue ain't showstopper =>

```
 public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, 
            string labelText, object htmlAttributes) where TModel : class
        {
            TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("label");
            builder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes)); // to convert an object into an IDictionary
            string value = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression); ;
            builder.InnerHtml = labelText;
            //the replaces shouldnt be necessary in the next statement, but there is a bug in the MVC framework that makes them necessary.
            builder.Attributes.Add("for", html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(value).Replace('[', '_').Replace(']', '_'));
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
        }
```